# How to check if NOT using Javascript bitwise operators?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I have a function that checks whether a user is premium by checking its flags:

```
isUserPremium() {
  return this.flags & Flags.PREMIUM; // returns true
}
```

Now let's say that I'd want another function, but this time to check whether the user is free, but using the same flag. I tried negating the returned value, but I'd like to know if there was a better way to do this.

```
isUserFree() {
  return !(this.flags & Flags.PREMIUM); // returns false
}
```

Comment: `return !isUserPremium()` ?

Comment: Bitwise operator & works on integers (and returns an integer), boolean operator && works on booleans (and returns a boolean).  if(integer)  will work in JS, but just be aware of what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way of checking whether a flag is not set with a single operator. I can suggest using `!isUserPremium()` instead of `isUserFree()` later in the code - don't create functions that invert a value returned from another function. However, make sure that you don't rely on this for security. Everything that is executing in the browser can be easily manipulated.

Comment: I was using simplified examples to find out if I can check whether a flag is not set. Thanks!